# Apollo subscriptions - Nextjs - Error: Observable cancelled prematurely at Concast.removeObserver

Tags: node.js, next.js, apollo-client, graphql-subscriptions

I am trying to use apollo/graphql subscription in my nextjs project, my graphql server is placed in external nextjs service,I can work with queries and mutation without any problem but when I use an implementation of useSubscription I get the following error:

> "Error: Observable cancelled prematurely
> at Concast.removeObserver (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/observables/Concast.js:118:33)
> at eval (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/observables/Concast.js:21:47)
> at cleanupSubscription (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/zen-observable-ts/module.js:92:7)
> at Subscription.unsubscribe (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/zen-observable-ts/module.js:207:7)
> at cleanupSubscription (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/zen-observable-ts/module.js:97:21)
> at Subscription.unsubscribe (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/zen-observable-ts/module.js:207:7)
> at eval (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/@apollo/client/react/hooks/useSubscription.js:106:26)
> at safelyCallDestroy (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22763:5)
> at commitHookEffectListUnmount (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22927:11)
> at invokePassiveEffectUnmountInDEV (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24998:13)
> at invokeEffectsInDev (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27137:11)
> at commitDoubleInvokeEffectsInDEV (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27110:7)
> at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26860:5)
> at flushPassiveEffects (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26796:14)
> at eval (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26592:9)
> at workLoop (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:266:34)
> at flushWork (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:239:14)
> at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:533:21)"

*I know that the subscriptions server is working right because I can to listening from apollo studio and I have created a spa with create-react-app and it works fine*

I have used:

**Server:**

- "apollo-server-express": "^3.6.7"
- "graphql-ws": "^5.7.0"

**Client**

- "next": "^12.1.5"
- "@apollo/client": "^3.5.10"
- "graphql-ws": "^5.7.0"

**Hook implementation**

```js
const room = useSubscription(
    gql`
      subscription onRoomAdded($roomAddedId: ID!) {
        roomAdded(id: $roomAddedId) {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    `
  );
```

**Client implementation**

```js
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache, split } from '@apollo/client';
import { GraphQLWsLink } from '@apollo/client/link/subscriptions';
import { getMainDefinition } from '@apollo/client/utilities';
import { createClient } from 'graphql-ws';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

const HOST = 'http://localhost:3001/graphql';
const HOST_WS = 'ws://localhost:3001/graphql';
const isServer = typeof window === 'undefined';

if (isServer) {
  global.fetch = fetch;
}

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: HOST,
});

const link = isServer
  ? httpLink
  : split(
      ({ query }) => {
        const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
        return (
          definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition' &&
          definition.operation === 'subscription'
        );
      },
      new GraphQLWsLink(
        createClient({
          url: HOST_WS,
        })
      ),
      httpLink
    );

const client = new ApolloClient({
  ssrMode: isServer,
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

export default client;
```

any idea about the problem? I think the problem could be that NextJS only works with subscriptions-transport-ws but in the official apollo documentation indicates that the new official way is to use graphql-ws the other library is unmaintained already

**UPDATE!**
I have checked that the subscriptions are working right in production build, I'm investigating how to implement in development process. any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it is working in production, but in not in dev, you may have the same issue I had with my React SPA: StrictMode and double rendering as [described in this github issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/6037).
So far I have found 2 ways to make it work:

1. remove `StrictMode`
2. subscribe with vanilla JS instead of`useSubscription`

```js
const ON_USER_ADDED = gql`
  subscription OnUserAdded {
    userAdded {
      name
      id
    }
  }
`;

const subscribe = () => {
client.subscribe({
  query: ON_USER_ADDED,
}).subscribe({
    next(data) {
      console.log('data', data);
    },
    complete(){
      console.log('complete');
    },
    error(err) {
      console.log('error', err);
    }
  })
};
```

Comment: In my case I had problems with reactStrictMode, thank you so much, May the Force be with you 

Comment: useSubscription works for me